# Translate VBA map into dart/flutter map

Tags: vba, flutter, dart

I am trying to translate VBA to dart and am having trouble. I believe it has to do with how I implement my xxMap and wMap. How do I make maps with keys that have two integers, then how do I use it? I have been trying to fix this for a while and just cannot figure it out. I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone can offer me! I truly hope you all have a good day!

Here is the VBA code:

```
Public Function CBND(X As Double, y As Double, rho As Double) As Double

Dim i As Integer, ISs As Integer, LG As Integer, NG As Integer
Dim XX(10, 3) As Double, W(10, 3) As Double
Dim h As Double, k As Double, hk As Double, hs As Double, BVN As Double, Ass As Double, asr As Double, sn As Double
Dim A As Double, b As Double, bs As Double, c As Double, d As Double
Dim xs As Double, rs As Double

W(1, 1) = 0.17132449237917
XX(1, 1) = -0.932469514203152
W(2, 1) = 0.360761573048138
XX(2, 1) = -0.661209386466265
W(3, 1) = 0.46791393457269
XX(3, 1) = -0.238619186083197

W(1, 2) = 4.71753363865118E-02
XX(1, 2) = -0.981560634246719
W(2, 2) = 0.106939325995318
XX(2, 2) = -0.904117256370475
W(3, 2) = 0.160078328543346
XX(3, 2) = -0.769902674194305
W(4, 2) = 0.203167426723066
XX(4, 2) = -0.587317954286617
W(5, 2) = 0.233492536538355
XX(5, 2) = -0.36783149899818
W(6, 2) = 0.249147045813403
XX(6, 2) = -0.125233408511469

W(1, 3) = 1.76140071391521E-02
XX(1, 3) = -0.993128599185095
W(2, 3) = 4.06014298003869E-02
XX(2, 3) = -0.963971927277914
W(3, 3) = 6.26720483341091E-02
XX(3, 3) = -0.912234428251326
W(4, 3) = 8.32767415767048E-02
XX(4, 3) = -0.839116971822219
W(5, 3) = 0.10193011981724
XX(5, 3) = -0.746331906460151
W(6, 3) = 0.118194531961518
XX(6, 3) = -0.636053680726515
W(7, 3) = 0.131688638449177
XX(7, 3) = -0.510867001950827
W(8, 3) = 0.142096109318382
XX(8, 3) = -0.37370608871542
W(9, 3) = 0.149172986472604
XX(9, 3) = -0.227785851141645
W(10, 3) = 0.152753387130726
XX(10, 3) = -7.65265211334973E-02
      
If Abs(rho) < 0.3 Then
  NG = 1
  LG = 3
ElseIf Abs(rho) < 0.75 Then
  NG = 2
  LG = 6
Else
  NG = 3
  LG = 10
End If
      
h = -X
k = -y
hk = h * k
BVN = 0
      
If Abs(rho) < 0.925 Then
  If Abs(rho) > 0 Then
    hs = (h * h + k * k) / 2
    asr = ArcSin(rho)
    For i = 1 To LG
      For ISs = -1 To 1 Step 2
        sn = Sin(asr * (ISs * XX(i, NG) + 1) / 2)
        BVN = BVN + W(i, NG) * Exp((sn * hk - hs) / (1 - sn * sn))
      Next ISs
    Next i
    BVN = BVN * asr / (4 * Pi)
  End If
  BVN = BVN + CND(-h) * CND(-k)
Else
  If rho < 0 Then
    k = -k
    hk = -hk
  End If
  If Abs(rho) < 1 Then
    Ass = (1 - rho) * (1 + rho)
    A = Sqr(Ass)
    bs = (h - k) ^ 2
    c = (4 - hk) / 8
    d = (12 - hk) / 16
    asr = -(bs / Ass + hk) / 2
    If asr > -100 Then BVN = A * Exp(asr) * (1 - c * (bs - Ass) * (1 - d * bs / 5) / 3 + c * d * Ass * Ass / 5)
    If -hk < 100 Then
      b = Sqr(bs)
      BVN = BVN - Exp(-hk / 2) * Sqr(2 * Pi) * CND(-b / A) * b * (1 - c * bs * (1 - d * bs / 5) / 3)
    End If
    A = A / 2
    For i = 1 To LG
      For ISs = -1 To 1 Step 2
        xs = (A * (ISs * XX(i, NG) + 1)) ^ 2
        rs = Sqr(1 - xs)
        asr = -(bs / xs + hk) / 2
        If asr > -100 Then
           BVN = BVN + A * W(i, NG) * Exp(asr) * (Exp(-hk * (1 - rs) / (2 * (1 + rs))) / rs - (1 + c * xs * (1 + d * xs)))
        End If
      Next ISs
    Next i
    BVN = -BVN / (2 * Pi)
  End If
  If rho > 0 Then
    BVN = BVN + CND(-Max(h, k))
  Else
    BVN = -BVN
    If k > h Then BVN = BVN + CND(k) - CND(h)
  End If
End If
CBND = BVN

End Function
```

Here is my dart/flutter translation:

```
import 'dart:math';
double cbnd (double X, double y, double rho) {
  int i;
  int iss;
  int lg;
  int ng;
  double h;
  double k;
  double hk;
  double hs;
  double bvn;
  double ass;
  double asr;
  double sn;
  double a;
  double b;
  double bs;
  double c;
  double d;
  double xs;
  double rs;

  Map<List<int>, double> wMap = {
    [1, 1] : 0.17132449237917,
    [2, 1] : 0.360761573048138,
    [3, 1] : 0.46791393457269,
    [1, 2] : 0.0471753363865118,
    [2, 2] : 0.106939325995318,
    [3, 2] : 0.160078328543346,
    [4, 2] : 0.203167426723066,
    [5, 2] : 0.233492536538355,
    [6, 2] : 0.249147045813403,
    [1, 3] : 0.0176140071391521,
    [2, 3] : 0.0406014298003869,
    [3, 3] : 0.0626720483341091,
    [4, 3] : 0.0832767415767048,
    [5, 3] : 0.10193011981724,
    [6, 3] : 0.118194531961518,
    [7, 3] : 0.131688638449177,
    [8, 3] : 0.142096109318382,
    [9, 3] : 0.149172986472604,
    [10, 3] : 0.152753387130726,
  };

  Map<List<int>, double> xxMap = {
    [1, 1] : -0.932469514203152,
    [2, 1] : -0.661209386466265,
    [3, 1] : -0.238619186083197,
    [1, 2] : -0.981560634246719,
    [2, 2] : -0.904117256370475,
    [3, 2] : -0.769902674194305,
    [4, 2] : -0.587317954286617,
    [5, 2] : -0.36783149899818,
    [6, 2] : -0.125233408511469,
    [1, 3] : -0.993128599185095,
    [2, 3] : -0.963971927277914,
    [3, 3] : -0.912234428251326,
    [4, 3] : -0.839116971822219,
    [5, 3] : -0.746331906460151,
    [6, 3] : -0.636053680726515,
    [7, 3] : -0.510867001950827,
    [8, 3] : -0.37370608871542,
    [9, 3] : -0.227785851141645,
    [10, 3] : -0.0765265211334973,
  };


  if (rho.abs() < 0.3) {
    ng = 1;
    lg = 3;
  }
  else if (rho.abs() < 0.75) {
    ng = 2;
    lg = 6;
  }
  else {
    ng = 3;
    lg = 10;
  }
  h = -X;
  k = -y;
  hk = h * k;
  bvn = 0;

  if (rho.abs() < 0.925) {
    if (rho.abs() > 0) {
      hs = (h * h + k * k) / 2;
      asr = arcSin(rho);
      for(i = 1; i < lg; i++) {
        for(iss = -1; iss < 1; iss+=2) {
          sn = sin(asr * (iss * xxMap[[i,ng]] + 1) / 2);
          bvn = bvn + wMap[[i,ng]] * exp((sn * hk - hs) / (1 - sn * sn));
        }
      }
      bvn = bvn * asr / (4 * pi);
    }
    bvn = bvn + cnd(-h) * cnd(-k);
  }
  else{
    if (rho < 0) {
      k = -k;
      hk = -hk;
    }
    if (rho.abs() < 1) {
      ass = (1 - rho) * (1 + rho);
      a = sqrt(ass);
      bs = pow((h - k), 2);
      c = (4 - hk) / 8;
      d = (12 - hk) / 16;
      asr = -(bs / ass + hk) / 2;
      if (asr > -100) {
        bvn = a * exp(asr) * (1 - c * (bs - ass)
            * (1 - d * bs / 5) / 3 + c * d * ass * ass / 5);
        if (-hk < 100) {
          b = sqrt(bs);
          bvn = bvn - exp(-hk / 2) * sqrt(2 * pi) * cnd(-b / a)
              * b * (1 - c * bs * (1 - d * bs / 5) / 3);
        }
        a = a / 2;
        for(i = 1; i < lg; i++) {
          for (iss = -1; iss < 1; iss+=2) {
            xs = pow(a * (iss * xxMap[{i, ng}] +1), 2);
            rs = sqrt(1 - xs);
            asr = -(bs / xs + hk) / 2;
            if (asr > -100) {
              bvn = bvn + a * wMap[{i, ng}] * exp(asr)
                  * (exp(-hk * (1 - rs) / (2 * (1 + rs))) / rs
                      - (1 + c * xs * (1 + d * xs)));
            }
          }
        }
        bvn = - bvn / (2 * pi);
      }
      if (rho > 0) {
        bvn = bvn + cnd(-max(h, k));
      }
      else {
        bvn = -bvn;
        if (k > h) {
          bvn = bvn + cnd(k) - cnd(h);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  print(bvn);
  return bvn;
}
```

Here is the error code:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 135ms.
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.6033458857722407
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.396061477681382
I/flutter ( 7281): 9588.900336837181
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.6066215038705733
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.39322784023367435
I/flutter ( 7281): 21.675664402433934
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.5567942331117398
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.43911123505550037
I/flutter ( 7281): 11.019478064121111
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.6067721597663256
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.3933784961294267
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.2265553776778987
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.5708243206704915
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.4261760665459637
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.1594404921802129
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.5331974688940583
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.4606874160295979
I/flutter ( 7281): 207.2825189948513
I/flutter ( 7281): 0.9045568943023813
E/flutter ( 7281): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '_mulFromInteger' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7281): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7281): Tried calling: _mulFromInteger(-1)
E/flutter ( 7281): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 7281): #1      int.* (dart:core-patch/integers.dart:16:38)
E/flutter ( 7281): #2      cbnd (package:flutter_apptest/main.dart:280:31)
E/flutter ( 7281): #3      ksi (package:flutter_apptest/main.dart:92:47)
E/flutter ( 7281): #4      bsAmericanCallApprox2002 (package:flutter_apptest/main.dart:57:67)
E/flutter ( 7281): #5      bsAmericanApprox2002 (package:flutter_apptest/main.dart:12:13)
E/flutter ( 7281): #6      main (package:flutter_apptest/main.dart:4:18)
E/flutter ( 7281): #7      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:25)
E/flutter ( 7281): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 7281): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 7281): #10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
E/flutter ( 7281): #11     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:12)
E/flutter ( 7281): #12     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:5)
E/flutter ( 7281): #13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
E/flutter ( 7281): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter ( 7281):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in these two lines:

```
xs = pow(a * (iss * xxMap[{i, ng}] +1), 2);
...
bvn = bvn + a * wMap[{i, ng}] * exp(asr)
```

You are passing in a `Set` as the `key` when you meant to pass a `List`.

Simply change the `{}` to `[]` like so:

```
xs = pow(a * (iss * xxMap[[i, ng]] +1), 2);
...
bvn = bvn + a * wMap[[i, ng]] * exp(asr)
```